# XAMPP and Skype Port Conflict on Windows 8

Tags: apache, xampp, skype

I have tried installing Skype on my machine and it takes aways the port for Apache (Port 80). How can I have both applications running at the same time? Note: I have tried changing Apache port to something else, but it doesn't work. Also when I boot my computer, Skype always run first and takes away the port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In skype >>

Go to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections and uncheck the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative".